# Directly access form element from form.FormController?

Tags: angularjs, delegates, angularjs-directive, components, decorator

I'm working on several components (directives) to aid in form validation. I'd like the components to be aware of the related input element's state (such as required). For example...

**Markup:**

```
<form name="editUser">
    <control-label input="editUser.name">Name</control-label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required/>
</form>
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive("controlLabel", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      input: "=input"
    },
    template:
      '<label class="control-label">'+
        '<span ng-transclude>{{label}}</span>'+
        '<span ng-if="input.required"> (required!)</span>'+ // doesn't work?
      '</label>'
  };
});
```

**Output:**

```
<form name="editUser">
    <label>
        <span>Name</span>
        <span>(required!)</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required/>
</form>
```

The source for [form.FormController](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js#L51) leaves me to believe this isn't possible. Is there any way to at least get access to the attrs on the element? I thought about using a decorator, but so far I haven't been able to figure out how that would be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `input.$validators.required` instead of `input.required` as:

```
myApp.directive("controlLabel", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      input: "=input"
    },
    template:
      '<label class="control-label">'+
        '<span ng-transclude>{{label}}</span>'+
        '<span ng-if="input.$validators.required"> (required!)</span>'+
      '</label>'
  };
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4776/)

Comment: @Brian: Use `input.$validators.required` then. Updated the answer above.

Comment: thanks @codeF0rmer, that's exactly what I was looking for. Didn't even know $validators existed :P

Answer (score 1):

First, there's an error in your code. If you're using `transclude`, you will have to declare it in your directive, or you will get an error.

As for your problem, within a directive, you can access DOM element. And for this particular use case, you can even get by without creating isolated scope or extra attribute at all:

```
app.directive("controlLabel", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: true,      // if needed, can also use empty isolated scope { }
        transclude: true, // must declare this
        template:
                '<label class="control-label">' +
                '<span ng-transclude>{{label}}</span>' +
                '<span ng-if="show"> (required!)</span>' +
                '</label>',
        link: function(scope, jqElem, attrs) {
            // check if next sibling of this directive is required
            scope.show = (jqElem.next().attr("required") === 'required');
        }
    };
});
```

Now your control label is really minimal and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and the logic is well encapsulated within a directive. The only requirement is that your `directive` target must be the next sibling of the label:

```
<control-label>Name</control-label>
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required/>
```

Of course, if needed, you can use your `jquery`-fu to change the `link` function to suit your other requirements.

Comment: Thanks @b0nyb0y. I guess I could also use the #id of the <input> to capture it's related <label> when the "for" attr is available. One question regarding scope: is the scope within the link function part of the parent scope or is it isolate? In your example above, i'm assuming the "show" value will not stomp on a $scope.$parent.show if it exists? Also, thx for pointed out the transclude error. I corrected it in my example.

Comment: @Brian Ah, you're right about the scope problem, my bad. Without declaring `scope`, every input will share the same `show` value under the whole controller. So I guess in this case, you can either **a)** declare `scope: true` (create child scope), or **b)** `scope: { }` (create isolated scope). Your choice depends on whether you want to inherit parent variables in directive scope or not. I'll fix the answer now.